# Window barColor equivalent for Android?

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a Titanium.UI.Window and I'm trying to set the background color of the title bar, an appropriate property seems to be "barColor" for iOS. Is there a "barColor" equivalent that I'm missing for Android? If not, what are some other common approaches to a more customizable title bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Actionbar `colorPrimary`  Sets the color of the action bar by using  a custom theme   :

`platform/android/res/values/custom_theme.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="materialTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
<item name="colorPrimary">#1565C0</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#0D47A1</item>
<item name="colorAccent">#FF80AB</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">#757575</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">#FF6E40</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">#FF4081</item>
<item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#BDBDBD</item>
<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#BDBDBD</item>
<item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">#FF4081</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

[image]
[image]

More details http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Themes